# What does this the 'tenor of one's affinity' mean

Tags: phrases

I'm reading a book(The Last Magician) and stumbled across this phrase. Googled and still didn't know what it meant.
Any guesses?

Sentence: "He could sense the strength and tenor of a person's affinity from ten paces."

Comment: Which part of the sentence did you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

Tenor has many meanings. For your case, it's not related to music.

> [**Tenor**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tenor)
>   *noun*
>
> 1. The general meaning, sense, or content of something.
>      *‘the general tenor of the debate’*

Applying it to the sentence you're asking about:

> He could sense the strength and **content/gist** of a person's affinity from ten paces.

Although "gist" is not mentioned in the dictionary, I think it fits well in the current case.

The author is trying to communicate that "He" is capable of understanding the ins and outs of another person's affinity, which means that "He" is capable of accurately defining and summarizing that person's affinity.

For reference:

> [**Gist**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gist)
>   *noun*
>
> 1. The substance or general meaning of a speech or text.
>      *‘it was hard to get the gist of Pedro's talk’*